# Modify how auto resize works on UIView?

Tags: ios, view, uiview, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I have a UIView that is sized to fit the entire screen minus 5 pixels on each side. I have set it to autoresize however this makes the view lose its 5 pixels on one side, and completely fills the sides when flipped horizontally. I need the 5 pixel buffer to exist in all orientations. Is there any way I can tweak the way auto resize works to make this happen?

My code:

```
[newsfeed setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Also, I have dragged one of the many views in from storyboard, and that one does not respond to the code above. How can I make it auto resize?

Comment: You should define it in the storyboard really, but your code will work. You need to ensure that all superviews resize appropriately too.

Comment: Most of my views are dynamically created in code, is there still a way to set it in story board? Also, for the one that was added in storyboard the box that usually comes with a view to auto resize isnt showing, how do I get there?

Answer (score 0):

When you also specify that the top and bottom margin are flexible, you in effect say that the left and right margins are fixed. Try this:

```
[newsfeed setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

As others have commented, this is more easily done in Interface Builder with springs and struts:

[image]

Comment: I dont want the left and right margins to be fixed though, just to auto-resize to take up most of the screen longways minus 5 pixels like in the vertical position. When I set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin my view tries to fill the whole screen, which is not desired behavior. I guess the top and bottom should be fixed.

Comment: @redIago, if your view is originally placed so that it's left and right margin are 5 pixels, the above mask keeps those margins. It will stretch horizontally to use all available space, keeping those margins.

Comment: After implementing your code, my views have completely disappeared.

Comment: @redIago, try posting more of your code (where you position the view initially).

Comment: I have signed NDA and cannot post most of my code. How would you set the margins to keep the 5 pixel thing right? I have hardcoded it with CGRect like CGRectMake(5,0,310,100). Is there a better way that supports Autoresize?